# When translating slang heavy text is my slang translator a co-translator?

Tags: translation, authorship

[Can one be a co-translator of a book, if he does not know the language that the book is translated into?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/44360/37695) made me realize I have a very similar question.

I was translating an extremely slang heavy book from A to B. I had a pretty good grasp on a more formal version of A and native in B and at the time at least I was knowledgeable about the slang of B. Now comes the helper person who doesn't speak B but explained slang A. UrbanDirectory in A, so to speak. What's this helper, then? At which percentage of slang does his work turn from 'explain a few phrases' to 'basically he translated the book from slang-A to A for me'? Is that even the relevant question here? (The translation never got published and this was twenty years ago.)

Comment: It seems like the top answer there fits here. Do you disagree?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can one be a co-translator of a book, if he does not know the language that the book is translated into?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44360/can-one-be-a-co-translator-of-a-book-if-he-does-not-know-the-language-that-the)

Comment: Feels like the question here is different than the linked "co-translator" question. Here we're talking about someone who is serving as a *dialect interpreter* or something within Language A, while the other question seems to be reference someone serving more of an organizational assistant role of some kind.

Comment: I of course agree with @TheLuckless

Comment: It seems to me that your assistant isn't so much a translator as an expert on a particular element within your translated work - no different (in a sense) from an expert on military aircraft, or surgical procedures, or 1920s culture (including slang), or court processes, or deep-sea diving. Many writers seek out and rely on such expert advice as a necessary research process in preparing their work, and the top answer in the dupe question covers how you might acknowledge such a role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your assistant *helped you in your research* for the translation. But you *did* the translation.**

A translation requires an understanding of what is being said in language A, but the process itself is based on finding the proper words *in language B*.
If your assistant had translated the slang into language B and you would have used this translation and maybe edited it slightly, then he/she would have been a co-translator. But since he/she only *explained* the slang to you in the same original language, there is no translation going on, so he/she is not a co-translator.

Of course, you should leave an acknowledgement if possible. "[Assistant] helped with the translation of [slang] by offering valuable explanations."

Side note: This hinges on the legal viewpoint that slang in language A is still fundamentally language A. However, some slang is so sophisticated and grammatically different that it could technically be a new language. The reason why it isn't is not *linguistically* motivated, but *politically*. The people speaking the slang/dialect do not have the political power and/or will to have it recognized as a language.